# Reproducing a cool chart - Better understanding reference classes in mutlinomial logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, classification, interpretation, multinomial-distribution

I am trying to reproduce this excellent data visualisation from the Economist https://www.economist.com/interactive/uk-general-election/build-a-voter

They have used multinomial logistic regression, and have created a "feature contribution" water-fall style chart to build-up voting intentions of defined demographic groups. I have a similar set of data (unrelated to politics!), and am trying to perform a similar analysis. The example below is a made-up, reproducible example in similar vein to the economist version. (Big thanks to chatgpt for writing the example quickly!)

**Can you help me interpret the co-efficients from the model output so that I can calculate the "waterfall values" of each level of the predictor variables?**

(NB. My understanding is that this is done in comparison with a reference class, which is what the model has done here. What I like about the economist version is that it presents as agnostic to a reference class, at least in the viz. I expect there is some dummy variable shenanigans going on, but I can't figure it out, and would love someone smarter to help!)

```
###### Load packages ###### 
require(tidyverse)
require(nnet)

###### Create example data set ###### 

set.seed(123) # Set seed for reproducibility

# Function to generate voting intention with different probabilities for each party
generate_voting_intention <- function(age_bracket, gender) {
  # Define base probabilities for Labour by age bracket
  base_prob_labour <- c("18-29"=0.45, "30-39"=0.40, "40-49"=0.38, "50-64"=0.36, "65+"=0.35)
  # Adjust Labour probability by gender
  gender_mod_labour <- ifelse(gender == "Female", 0.05, 0)
  prob_labour <- base_prob_labour[age_bracket] + gender_mod_labour
  
  # Conservative base probabilities (smaller than Labour's to ensure Labour majority)
  base_prob_conservative <- c("18-29"=0.25, "30-39"=0.30, "40-49"=0.32, "50-64"=0.34, "65+"=0.35)
  # Adjust Conservative probability by gender (no gender modification in this example)
  prob_conservative <- base_prob_conservative[age_bracket]
  
  # The remaining probability is for Lib Dems
  prob_lib_dems <- 1 - prob_labour - prob_conservative
  
  # Sample voting intention based on calculated probabilities
  sample(c("Labour", "Conservative", "Lib Dems"), size = 1, prob = c(prob_labour, prob_conservative, prob_lib_dems))
}

# Create a data frame with the specified variables
create_survey_data <- function(n) {
  age_brackets <- c("18-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-64", "65+")
  genders <- c("Male", "Female")
  
  # Sample age and gender for each respondent
  ages <- sample(age_brackets, n, replace = TRUE)
  genders <- sample(genders, n, replace = TRUE)
  
  # Generate voting intention for each respondent
  voting_intention <- mapply(generate_voting_intention, age_bracket = ages, gender = genders)
  
  # Combine into a data frame
  data.frame(
    Age = ages,
    Gender = genders,
    VotingIntention = voting_intention,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}

# Generate survey data for 1000 respondents
survey_data <- create_survey_data(1000)

###### Build Voting Intention model ###### 

vote_mod<-multinom(VotingIntention~Age + Gender, data=survey_data)

tidy_vote_mod<-tidy(vote_mod,exponentiate = TRUE)
```

Comment: it probably just uses the model predictions.  so your question is essentially "how do I get predicted probabilities from a multinomial regression'?  which is essentially a programming question.

Comment: You can directly get the model coefficients and population weights from [here](https://cdn.economistdatateam.com/2023-uk-poll-tracker/build-a-voter/coefs-future-vote.csv) (and [here](https://cdn.economistdatateam.com/2023-uk-poll-tracker/build-a-voter/coefs-mod-ge2019.csv) is the 2019 model).

Comment: @PBulls this is exactly the data structure I need - but I can't figure out how they've transformed the outputs of the model to these outcome probabilities (they are labelled here as "coef" but am not sure that's quite right?

Comment: @RobinSheridan They are almost certainly the model coefficients, that is, additive parameter estimates in the log-odds scale. There's a lot of interactions involved so to obtain the probabilities you'd sum, most likely in order of the effects (i.e. first is region, then region+age\*region, then region+age\*region+sex\*age\*region..), and take the inverse logit to get a probability.